# Remove Quick Links and Account from Magento CE 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

I commented out the the block in the page.xml (app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/page.xml)
See screen shot.
I then cleared my browser cache but still they still show on the footer.

Is there anything else I need to do??? Please Help

[image]

Comment: Try to use template path hints(http://bit.ly/1EKfNXg) and locate which .phtml file is showing the links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the local.xml just remove them instead of commenting them out. Using this.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="footer">
            <remove name="footer_links"/>
            <remove name="footer_links2"/>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Comment: Hi thank for this. I added the local.xml to the same location, cleared browser cache and it's still there. I removed the 'comment outs' from the page.xml but the blocks are still in there. Do I need to remove them completely? Because I did that and still nothing.

This is my first time dealing with a vanilla install so i'm a novice at the moment.

Comment: Did you add my code above ? You hopefully changed it ti the names you need

Comment: I disabled the static block which is named incorrectly and that removes them both. And the local.xml works. Thanks for your help!